# how to setup wireless in Kubuntu

Tags: wireless-networking, kubuntu

My network adapter is Broadcom 43225 802.11b/g/n

I don't know hot how to find it and how to install it.

in WIN7 everything done automatically!!!

maybe thats the reason why ordinary people keep using windows...